# Ethernet Adapter not found/working [Ubuntu 23.10]

Tags: drivers, server, ethernet, raspberrypi, 23.10

I am using a Raspberry Pi expansion board, Zero to Pi 4.
[https://www.amazon.com/dp/B0BVLPB988?psc=1&ref=ppx_yo2ov_dt_b_product_details](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B0BVLPB988)

It works plug-n-play in the native Raspberry Pi OS.
However, for some reason the Ethernet port does not work in Ubuntu 23.10. It loads everything else (USB)!

I need the Ethernet to work in Ubuntu. Can you guys please help me get this Ethernet port working?
Perhaps a "global" driver? 
Typical windows user strategy

As requested, here are the outputs:

- **dmesg -T**: https://qtext.io/q72w
- **dmidecode**:

```terminal
# dmidecode 3.5
# No SMBIOS nor DMI entry point found, sorry.
```

- **lshw**: https://qtext.io/upjh
- **lspci**: no output
- **lsusb**:

```terminal
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 346d:5678 USB Disk 2.0
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 346d:5678 USB Disk 2.0
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 1a40:0101 Terminus Technology Inc. Hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

- **lsmode**: https://qtext.io/57nn
- **ip link**:

```
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
2: wlan0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP mode DORMANT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether a1:2b:cd:34:e5:c6 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
```

This is what shows up under Raspberry Pi OS:

```terminal
sudo lshw -class network
  *-network:0
       description: Ethernet interface
       physical id: 2
       bus info: usb@1:1.1
       logical name: eth0
       serial: ff:a1:2b:c3:4d:e5
       size: 100Mbit/s
       capacity: 100Mbit/s
       capabilities: ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8152 driverversion=v1.12.13 duplex=full ip=10.10.10.09 link=yes multicast=yes port=MII speed=100Mbit/s
  *-network:1
       description: Wireless interface
       physical id: 3
       logical name: wlan0
       serial: f6:7g:h8:i9:0j:1k
       capabilities: ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=brcmfmac driverversion=7.45.96 firmware=es7 multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
```

Answer (score 1):

Yah, a "global" driver is unlikely :-).

You haven't yet given us much to work with.  To get started, do the following under both Raspberry Pi OS and Ubuntu 23.10

1. Check the output of `dmesg -T` (-T shows a timestamp, which may be inaccurate), looking for boot-time kernel messages about your hardware or its manufacturer.
2. Check the output of various hardware reporting commands, looking for the name or manufacturer of your hardware: `dmidecode`, `lshw`, `lspci`, `lsusb`.
3. List kernel modules which have been loaded using `lsmod`.
4. Check the output of `ip link`, which lists network interfaces.  This may indicate that the interface is present but not configured.

With the information collected, you can learn:

- what Raspberry Pi OS detected, and how it handled it correctly
- what Ubuntu detected, what it tried, what it got wrong, and/or possibly what it didn't like about the device

--klode

Comment:  Thanks, I'll update my question ASAP

Comment: I'm new to linux so even with all this info, I have no idea what's going on.

Comment: No worries, that's expected.  It's the same sort of tasks, regardless of OS: check hardware detection, check drivers and/or services, check configuration, check functionality.  Three things: 1) your texts don't seem to be there, all I see is "Hi.  You can type something here."; 2) it's `lsmod` (no "e"); 3) It would help most if you could run all of the commands under both OSes, then we compare and contrast.

Comment: What would be the best avenue to share the outputs? I can't do it here because they are way too long and get me over the limit of characters

Comment: The StackExchange community meta.AskUbuntu recommends https://paste.ubuntu.com/, with the understanding that the service is impermanent by design.  Other communities recommend pastebin.com, or github, or Google drive.  All StackExchange discussions that I found seem to discourage overbroad use, but some recognize the usefulness in specific case such as for log files, which seems to be the case here.  Whatever you use, I recommend that we ensure the relevant snippets end up in either your question or an accepted answer.